# EF: Complex Property instance value is not accessible in Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation

I have 2 classes

## Customer

```
    public class Customer {
    public bool PORequired { get; set; }
}
```

## Order

```
public class Order {
    public string PONumber { get; set; }
    public Customer CustomerInstance { get; set; }

    public override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> 
                       Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (CustomerInstance.PORequired && string.IsNullOrEmpty(PONumber))
        {
            AddValidationError(new ValidationResult("PO is mandatory 
                                         in Orders for this Customer"));
        }
        return ValidationErrors;
    }
}
```

In Order class, I'm trying to do a validation as given above, but could not access CustomerInstance as it is null.

Before validation, through EF code, I'm populating the object from database with Customer Information, but while it is passing through the validationcontext it seems empty.

```
OrderSvc.PopulateFromDatabase(order); //Populate the object from DB.
order.PONumber = "";                  // Setting the PONumber as blank for testing.
OrderSvc.Update(order); // Here order object has CustomerInstance with all the values.
OrderSvc.SaveChanges(); // In the next line, the validation method throws error that    customerinstance is empty.
```

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Does your `Order` class inherits interfaces? Because you are overriding `Validate` method, but you doesn't inherit `IValidateObject` interface.

Comment: Yes, I've a base class for all the entities which has IValidateObject interface. While debugging the code, simple property validations are working, facing issue only in complex type scenario like above. Even navigation collections are loaded for my other requirements.

Comment: Can you show the code for `OrderSvc.Update`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom validation, make sure your class inherits **IValidatableObject**. Make the change below:

```
public class Order : IValidatableObject // <-- Goes here
{
   // Properties here
}
```

And make sure you call **ModelState.IsValid** before you attempt to write to the Database:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) {
   // Write to db
}
```